# Rails gem multiple NOSQL datastores

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nosql

I'm creating my own gem and I want to enable user to save data to multiple NOSQL data stores. How can I make this happen? Where should I place the necessary files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done the same thing in my gem. I think you have created an App folder in your gem/engine. Create another folder called "backend" and create classes for each datastore. For my case I created a seperate for Mongo and Redis

```
module Memberfier
  class RedisStore
    def initialize(redis)
      @redis = redis
    end

    def keys
      @redis.keys
    end

    def []=(key, value)
      value = nil if value.blank?
      @redis[key] = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(value)
    end

    def [](key)
      @redis[key]
    end

    def clear_database
      @redis.keys.clone.each {|key| @redis.del key }
    end
  end
end


module Memberfier
  class MongoStore
    def initialize(collection)
      @collection = collection
    end

    def keys
      @collection.distinct :_id
    end

    def []=(key, value)
      value = nil if value.blank?
      collection.update({:_id => key},
                        {'$set' => {:value => ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(value)}},
                        {:upsert => true, :safe => true})
    end

    def [](key)
      if document = collection.find_one(:_id => key)
        document["value"]
      else
        nil
      end
    end

    def destroy_entry(key)
      @collection.remove({:_id => key})
    end

    def searchable?
      true
    end

    def clear_database
      collection.drop
    end

    private

    def collection; @collection; end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have already seen one of Uncle Bob's presentations on application architecture. If not, it's [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpkDN78P884). I'd recommend having a single boundary object that select models inherit from. That boundary object could have multiple CRUD methods such as `find`, `create`, `delete`. That boundary object could inherit from whatever NOSQL adapter you configure. Example/source: http://hawkins.io/2014/01/pesistence_with_repository_and_query_patterns/